# control edge width with value and width in r visnetwork package

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I'm trying to visualize my network with visNetwork package. But I found myself totally confused about controling node size and edge width. In the first example, I set `value=1` in nodes and `value=0.1`in edges. In the second example, I set `value=10` in nodes and `width=0.1` in edges. However, in both graphs, size of nodes appear to be the same. Changing edge width seems to work with `width` not `value`. I don't know why. I did see people use `value` in edges for edge width control. 
Can anyone clarify me on this issue? Also, what is the range of values for node size and edge width?

```
nodes1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:10),# add labels on nodes
                    value = 1,  #**
                    color = c("darkblue"))   
edges1 <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10,8),
                    to = sample(1:10, 8),
                    value = 0.1  #**
                    ) 
visNetwork::visNetwork(nodes1, edges1, width = "150%", physics=F) 

nodes2 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:10),# add labels on nodes
                    value = 10,  #**
                    color = c("darkblue"))   
edges2 <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10,8),
                    to = sample(1:10, 8),
                    width = 0.1 #**
                    ) 
visNetwork::visNetwork(nodes2, edges2, width = "150%", physics=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like size of the nodes works based on comparison . If it is set one value than graph just reflect the same size of nodes on optimal scale, thus it is not changed
if you put value equal to different number you'll see nodes of different size

```
nodes2 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                     label = paste("Node", 1:10),# add labels on nodes
                     value = 1:10, #**
                     color = c("darkblue"))   
edges2 <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10,8),
                     to = sample(1:10, 8),
                     width = 0.1 #**
) 
visNetwork::visNetwork(nodes2, edges2, width = "150%", physics=F)
```

[image]